# Jamaican citizen with C1/D visa would like to transit in JFK

Tags: visas

My friend from Jamaica has C1/D visa as he works on the ship. He'd like to visit me in Asia during his vacation. We are wondering if he can use the C1/D visa to transfer in JFK airport (he will need to collect his luggages and check in again tho.) or he needs to apply a transit visa? 
He called the US embassy in Jamaica and they said the C1/D is from joining the ship only. 
I wonder has anyone with C1/D visa successfully transit in the US?

Comment: You got wrong information from the embassy (which is unfortunately very common). As indicated in the linked post, C1 can be used for personal travel. D is for crewmember travel. A C1/D visa can be used for both. You can't get a transit visa because you already have it!